# Codeigniter Prevent Passing Parameter to Function to Avoid Non-Existent URI Segment

Tags: php, codeigniter, function, parameters, uri

So I have a page:

http://www.mysite.com/controller/function

The function is defined in the controller as:

```
function ()
{
//some stuff here
}
```

However it is possible to resolve the URL:
http://www.mysite.com/controller/function/blablabla

i.e. "blablabla" can be passed to the function and forms an additional URI segment, but still brings up the same page. I have the same issue with a number of controllers / functions - how do I prevent parameters being passed to the function (or appearing as a URI segment)?

I've been working with Codeigniter and PHP for around 6 months very part time, so forgive me if the answer is obvious but my searches haven't been fruitful on this.

My goal is optimised SEO - unsure whether better to redirect the page with the extra URI segment to the correct page or to the 404 page.

Comment: A related inquiry into this issue: [Prevent arbitrary URL parameters](https://forum.codeigniter.com/thread-76396.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't prevent that without changing how CI handles URI parsing.

You could force a redirect like so:

```
function my_happy_function($redirect=null) {
   if($redirect) {
   redirect('/controller/my_happy_function/');
   }
}
```

That would strip out any variables that are given in the URI, at the cost of a page redirect.

Comment: Thankyou. Probably expensive in terms of code bloat across the site, so perhaps not worth worrying about from an SEO point of view!

Comment: You're welcome! Yeah, it's generally not necessary and using the parameters can be very helpful.

Since I answered this, do you mind marking it as accepted? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want a generic catch all for pages. You can do this using routes.

For example:

```
$route['my_happy_function(/:any)*'] = "my_happy_function";
```

then in your my_happy_function index method you check the URI segments there...

```
public function index()
{
    $something = $this->uri->segment(1);
    $something_else = $this->uri->segment(2);
    // etc

}
```

this way all calls to my_happy_function get pushed to the index method...

wait, did I understand your question correctly? If I missed the point let me know and I can update.

Comment: Thanks, it was more about preventing people creating unusual backlinks so a redirect to the 404 page would maybe be better. For example someone could do www.mysite/controller/function/lotsofnaughtywords and the URL would resolve